# Swap pointers in two different classes using one function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, swap

I have two classes A and B that should both use two pointers of a third class P. A pointer of class B is created in class A and the two pointers are passed as parameters (here is the problem that I don't know how exactly). There is also a swap() function inside of B which should swap the pointers also in A.
I don't know how to pass the pointers of A to B in order to swap them in both classes (A,B).
Do they have to be defined globally? Or is it possible to pass the addresses and swap those?

```
Class B:
{
public:
    B(P *p1, P *p2) 
    {
        mB_p1 = p1;
        mB_p2 = p2;
    };

private:
    P *mB_p1;
    P *mB_p2;

    void swapPointers();
}


Class A:
{
public:
    A() 
    {
        mA_p1 = new P();
        mA_p2 = new P();
        a = new B(mA_p1, mA_p2); 
    };

    B *b;

private:
    P *mA_p1;
    P *mA_p2;
}


B::swapPointers() 
{
    P *temp;
    temp = mB_p1;
    mB_p1 = mB_p2;
    mB_p2 = mB_p1;
}
```

As far as I know is that I have two classes with two pointers each now. When I swap them using B's swap function, nothing happens to the pointers in A, which is what I would like to change. Though I don't know what's the right way.

Comment: although the whole idea looks dangerous, you could pass to be not pointers to P but rather pointers to A's fields mA_p<N> (that is P**) and then make the swap. But again this would contradict one of the basic principles of OOP: data encapsulation

Comment: I guess I am going to overthink my design again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a very nice design, and I do wonder why this is necessary in your program.  In any case, you could achieve this with references and thus avoid mutual dependence between the two classes (*i.e.* you could easily re-use `B` to create horrible bugs in *other* parts of your program too):

```
class B
{
public:
    B( P * &p1, P * &p2 ) 
        : mB_p1( p1 )
        , mB_p2( p2 )
    {
    }

private:
    P * &mB_p1;
    P * &mB_p2;

    void swapPointers()
    {
        std::swap( mB_p1, mB_p2 );
    }
}
```

Now, `B` stores references to pointers, and so swapping the references will actually swap the values of the pointers being referred to.

By the way, don't forget to `delete b;` in the destructor for `A`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this if B has also a pointer to A and is a friend of A. The you can also swap the pointers in A within the `swapPointers()` function.

By the way, your swap implementation is wrong.

```
B::swapPointers() 
{
    P* temp = mB_p1;
    mB_p1 = mB_p2;
    mB_p2 = temp;
}
```